# Count()over() have repeated records

Tags: sql

I often use sum() over() to calculate cumulative value，but today，I tried count ()over()，the result is out of my expectation，can someone explain why the result have repeated records on the same day？

I know the regular way is to count (distinct I'd) group by date，and then sum()over(order by date)，just curious for the result of "count(id）over(order by date)"

```
Select pre.date,count(person_id) over (order by pre.date)
From (select distinct person_id, date from events) pre
```

The result will be repeated records for the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your outer query has not filtered or aggregated the results from the inner query.  It returns the same number of rows.

You want aggregation:

```
select pre.date, count(*) as cnt_on_date,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by pre.date) as running_count
from (select distinct person_id, date from events) pre
group by pre.date;
```

Comment: I get it！Thanks so much：）

Answer (score 0):

Almost all analytical functions, except `row_number()` which comes to mind, do not differentiate ties for the same value of columns in `order by` clause. In some documentation it is stated directly:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97469)

> If you specify a logical window with the `RANGE` keyword, then the function returns the same result for each of the rows

- [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/tutorial-window.html)

> By default, if `ORDER BY` is supplied then the frame consists of all rows from the start of the partition up through the current row, **plus any following rows that are equal to the current row according to the `ORDER BY` clause**.

- [My SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html)

> With 'ORDER BY': The default frame includes rows from the partition start through the current row, *including all peers of the current row (rows equal to the current row according to the `ORDER BY` clause)*.

But in general, the addition of `ORDER BY` in analytical clause implicitly sets window specification to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. As window calculation is made for each row in the defined window, with default to `RANGE` rows with the same value of `ORDER BY` columns will come into the same window and will produce the same result. So to have a real running total, there should be `ROWS BETWEEN` or more detail column in `ORDER BY` part of analytic clause. Functions that does not support windowing clause are exception of this rule, but it sometimes not documented directly, so I will not try to list them here. Functions that can be used as aggregate are not exception in general and produce the same value.